# How can I solve the problem of NaN value?

Tags: javascript

I want to sum the values of an array but I get an error with NaN
could you help me please?

```
const products = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'T-Shirt',
        price: 98,
        quantity: 10
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Shoes',
        price: 70,
        quantity: 17
    }
]

let cartItems = []
let parsIntPrice
let totalPrice = 0

const shoppingCart = (myId) => {

    localStorage.setItem('myProduct', JSON.stringify(products))
    const getStorage = localStorage.getItem('myProduct')
    const finalProducts = JSON.parse(getStorage)
    // SHOW EACH ITEM SELECTED
    let selectedResult = finalProducts.filter(item => item.id === myId)
    for (let product in selectedResult) {
        console.log(selectedResult[product].title)

        // CALCULATE TOTAL PRICES
        parsIntPrice = selectedResult[product].price
        totalPrice = cartItems.reduce((firstItem, secondItem) => firstItem + secondItem.parsIntPrice, 0)
        console.log(`Total Price is: ${totalPrice}`)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the error log, please?

Comment: error is, 
Total Price is: NaN

Comment: @gavgrif, parsInt is just a name of variable not a method

Comment: Btw `cartItems` remains as empty after initialization as is, thus, `totalPrice = cartItems.reduce(...` won't come up with the expected result either. Another suggestion is that one does not try to accomplish too many things a time; e.g `shoppingCart` might be broken down into two functions, a)one that actually collects a list of products (by `myId`), which I suppose, then is the list of shopping cart items and b)another one that computes (via reduce) the total price from the latter list. This immediately cleans up the code, thus it is better readable, debuggable and refactoring is less painful

Comment: To uphold data integrity, you should only store a list of `id` in the `localStorage` and not the whole object. The products and prices can change and are already defined in `products`, which I suspect are going to get fetched from a database at one point.

Comment: Another suggestion ... clean up your code by precisely naming every method and data(variable) of what it does and/or contains. I tried to refactor the provided code, but I had to stop because one only can guess if e.g. `selectedResult` will be ever an array of many product items or just does contain exactly a single item or none, due to not knowing if `id` is unique to each product ... and so on ...

Comment: Of cause the main reason ending up with `NaN` is that the `reduce` method's `secondItem` is at best a product item which does not feature a `parsIntPrice ` property. Thus with the first reducing iteration step one already does return a `NaN` value (due to `0 + undefined` which equals a `NaN` value) which again is the base for the next summation. But the result of any operation that processes a number value with/against a `NaN` value of cause will be a `NaN` value itself.

Comment: Hi - I spotted that parsInt is a variable and so deleted my comment. But I would STRONGLY suggest against naming variables with names that are so closely related to js methods (parsInt / parseInt) It makes for very confusing reading - IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `cartItems` array is empty, so reduce doesn't iterate it

Comment: cartItem doesn't empty:        cartItems.push(JSON.stringify(`Product Title: ${[selectedResult[product].title]} - Price: ${[selectedResult[product].price]}`))

Comment: @Parisa ... make this new information part of the provided example code then.

Comment: Another thing, how does the OP expect the `cartItems`' reduce method to operate, if each item is a `string` type ... namely a stringified subversion of a product item.

Comment: @Peter Seliger: Thank you for your answers